# How can I provide multiple folders using bean shell pre processor to read files using jmter thread

Tags: shell, jmeter

How can I provide multiple folders using bean shell pre processor to read files using jmter thread?

I tried to upload multiple files using bean Pre processor and Http request sampler sending all files present is folder provded for one thread.

If I do have different folders for different thread it is requred to provide dynamic path/parameterized path for bean pre processer.

*I want to make dynamic path for 'path_to_your_folder'*

bean shell pre processor configuration:
[Bean Shell pre processor configuration image as below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3Ym9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parameterize file path using CSV data set config and use the parameter in your beanshell..

Create a CSV file containing all paths.
Add a [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to your test plan and configure your CSV ,give variable name as shown below

[image]

In your pre-processor you can use vars.get("Variablename") to get file path as shown below
[image]

For more info on beanshell please read [this article.](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/06/4878/)

however its recommended to use JSR223 sampler with groovy as the performance is much better compared to beanshell..
Please let me know if it helps